# Give name to image when used intent camera

Tags: java, android, image, save, mediastore

In my app, I open the camera and want to save that file with a specific name.
I use this code:

```
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File("new-photo-name.jpg")) );
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

}
protected void onActivityResult1(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                          Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
                    }   
}
```

It does open the camera, I can take and save the photo, but it does not give the good name.
Everytime when I save the picture, he gives the picture an other name, 1 name example is: "13333675392558.jpg". I don't understand how he comes with that kind of numbers.

Why does my code does not apply the name: "new-photo-name.jpg" ?

And/Or what do I wrong then?

Thanks already, Bigflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, but don't know the exact same problem yet, but this code worked for me:

```
private Uri outputFileUri;
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/DCIM/Camera/new-photo-name.jpg");

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
```

onLongPress has something to do with gesture (touch) actions, you could also use a button here.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE){
            System.out.println("string of file name = "+outputFileUri.toString());
      }
}
```

Really small code, but works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
```

is the line that sets the filename. It's this line you must change.

Comment: Changed it to: `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "new-photo-name.jpg");` But somehow, this didn't work.

Comment: String is not Uri. I dunno if this is the best, my app uses Uri.fromFile(new File(String fileName))

Comment: I changed the code, so it is much more easier to look at. But this also isn't working :(

Comment: I just noticed " onActivityResult1 " in your code. Is there really a " 1 " in here? Please remove it, if there is, and try again :)

Comment: Oh, I removed it, but somehow, it still isn't working. I think it goes somewhere else wrong in the code, I will search for the problem now.